# Jlist - ClearSelection with observer pattern

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, observer-pattern, jlist

This is my first post, I'm having an issue in my application, I'm programing in Java.

I need to implement the observer pattern, because I have a main window and I need to add elements. When I add a element then the main window should be updated. I put the implements and extends Observable and Observer in the right classes and in the main window, I also  override the update method. But when the update executes it throws me an exception.

Here is the code and the exeption:

```
@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {

    // Update Hotels
    this.popularHoteles(unDepartamento.getListaHoteles());

}
private void popularHoteles(ArrayList<Hotel> Hoteles) {

    listaHoteles.removeAll();

    if (fechasCorrectas()) {
        listaHoteles.setListData(Hoteles.toArray());
    }
}
```

where "listaHoteles" is a Jlist item on my from.

when i execute the setListDadta i recive this exeption:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   diaztaranto.interfaces.MenuPrincipal.listaHotelesValueChanged(MenuPrincipal.java:937)
>     at
>   diaztaranto.interfaces.MenuPrincipal.access$800(MenuPrincipal.java:20)
>     at
>   diaztaranto.interfaces.MenuPrincipal$9.valueChanged(MenuPrincipal.java:345)
>     at javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(JList.java:1798)     at
>   javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(JList.java:1812)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:184)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:164)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:211)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:405)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:415)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.removeSelectionIntervalImpl(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:576)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.clearSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:420)
>     at javax.swing.JList.clearSelection(JList.java:2045)    at
>   diaztaranto.interfaces.MenuPrincipal.popularHoteles(MenuPrincipal.java:998)
>     at
>   diaztaranto.interfaces.MenuPrincipal.update(MenuPrincipal.java:1043)
>     at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Observable.java:159)    at
>   java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Observable.java:115)     at
>   diaztaranto.dominio.Hotel.agregarComentario(Hotel.java:212)   at
>   diaztaranto.interfaces.Evaluacion.botonEvaluarActionPerformed(Evaluacion.java:135)
>     at diaztaranto.interfaces.Evaluacion.access$000(Evaluacion.java:6)
>     at
>   diaztaranto.interfaces.Evaluacion$1.actionPerformed(Evaluacion.java:56)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

any one knows why this is happen?

Thanks in advice!

Comment: as i see the problem is in ClearSelection method but i dont know clear why this is the problem

Comment: quite not possible to answering this question based on code posted, description and this.whatever, for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JList/DefaultListModel

Comment: Please add some code from the place where your NPE is thrown (`diaztaranto.interfaces.MenuPrincipal.listaHotelesValueChanged`)